# pyspark big when clause stuck

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

Cluster: Driver: i3.2xlarge, Workers: i3.2xlarge, 8-16 workers, On-Demand, Databricks 7.3 LTS (Spark 3.0.1)

I have a WHEN clause with around 2500 conditions and my job ends up getting stuck and not finish with 0 active tasks and 0 stages for a long time and never finishes.
Is there a way to rewrite this in a better way ?

```
def for_exist_column(df, col, pre):
    if col in df.columns:
        return pre(df[col])
    else:
        return f.lit(False)

df=df.withColumn("flag", f.when((for_exist_column(df, 'L8A', lambda c: c=='C') & for_exist_column(df, 'B2B', lambda c: c=='B') & for_exist_column(df, 'B2C', lambda c: c=='B') & for_exist_column(df, 'U4N', lambda c: c=='C') & for_exist_column(df, 'B3N', lambda c: c=='B') & for_exist_column(df, 'U4C', lambda c: c=='C')) 

                              | (for_exist_column(df, 'L8A', lambda c: c=='C') & for_exist_column(df, 'B2B', lambda c: c=='D') & for_exist_column(df, 'B2C', lambda c: c=='B') & for_exist_column(df, 'U4N', lambda c: c=='C') & for_exist_column(df, 'B3N', lambda c: c=='I') & for_exist_column(df, 'U4C', lambda c: c=='B')) | 
                              | (for_exist_column(df, 'L8A', lambda c: c=='C') & for_exist_column(df, 'B2B', lambda c: c=='D') & for_exist_column(df, 'B2C', lambda c: c=='B') & for_exist_column(df, 'U4N', lambda c: c=='C') & for_exist_column(df, 'B3N', lambda c: c=='I'))
                              | ... 2000 other conditions
                )
```

edit:
Trying to create a pandas_udf equivalent of the above. Any help would be much appreciated...

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, pandas_udf
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true")
df=spark.read.parquet("s3://tempOutforWith.csv")

@pandas_udf('string', PandasUDFType.SCALAR)  #not sure if this is correct
def for_exist_column(df: pd.DataFrame, col: str, pre: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    if col in df.columns:
        return pd.Series(pre(df[col]))
    else:
        return pd.Series(False)

df=df.withColumn("flag", f.when((for_exist_column(df, 'L8A', lambda c: c=='C') & for_exist_column(df, 'B2B', lambda c: c=='B') & for_exist_column(df, 'B2C', lambda c: c=='B') & for_exist_column(df, 'U4N', lambda c: c=='C') & for_exist_column(df, 'B3N', lambda c: c=='B') & for_exist_column(df, 'U4C', lambda c: c=='C')),1).otherwise(0))
display(df)
```

Getting the below error:

```
TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: DataFrame[B2B: string, B2C: string, B3N: string, L8A: string, U1A: string, U4C: string, U4N: string, Dummy: bigint, Katashiki: string] of type <class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>. 
For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.
```

Comment: Could you please share the logical and physical plans with df.explain(True) ?

Comment: This is probably a case where the query optimizer is taking too long.  If you check the driver logs, you might see something interesting.  Do you really have 2500 unique flags?  If so, this might make sense to wrap the logic in a pyspark pandas udf.  Normally what youre doing is correct, but since you have 2500 checks, then the query optimizer is probably where the query is paused.  You can validate this, by just using 1 check, instead of 2500.  If it runs right away, we can safely assume its the optimizer thats the bottleneck and putting the logic in the pandas udf as the correct path forward

Comment: @JoeWiden, tbnks for the suggestion. Looks like thats whats happening. It's running when I give only one condition, but with the full set, just hangs. Could you plz suggest the equivalent pyspark pandas udf for the above ?